# Delta Function as a differential

Tags: limits, functions

I wanted to know why the following relation works:

$$\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\pi t} \frac{\sin^2(x t)}{x^2} d x = \delta (x) dx\text{ as } t\to     \infty
\end{equation} $$

It comes up in the case of Fermi's Golden Rule.

Had to write something just so that the bot would allow me to correct my equation!

Comment: i guess u should integrate it against a suitable testfunction

Comment: as t approaches infinity

Comment: Define the differential $\delta_t (x)dx =\frac{1}{\pi t}\frac{\sin^2(xt)}{x^2}dx$and integrate it against a suitable testfunction (of Schwartz class should be sufficient) $f(x)$:

$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}dx\delta_t (x)f(x)
$$

now change the variable $xt=y, dy=dx/t$. Can u take it home from there?

Comment: Related question on Phys.SE http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/240191/2451